# figuring out method return type change

Tags: java, jsp

I have the following class inside an `Order` class and I want to return an object instead of string from the following method.

```
public String getCarLocationDisplay() {

        String result = "";
        if (carHandler != null) {
            result = carHandler.getAttribute(CarHandler.CAR_LOCATION);
        }
        return result;
}
```

In my JSP I am accessing it like this based on the above method:

```
<td>
      <a 
        href="cardetails.htm?id=<c:out value="${viewOrder.carLocationDisplay}"/>" 
        class = "urllink"><bean:write name="viewOrder"
        property="carLocationDisplay" /></a>
</td>
```

I have created a separate class (called `CarLocationDisplay`) which I'm thinking of using it inside `getCarLocationDisplay` method above so that I could return an object maybe and in the JSP I can have something like `${viewOrder.carLocationDisplay.id}` or `${viewOrder.carLocationDisplay.name}`

```
public class CarLocationDisplay {
    private CarLocationManager carLocMgr;
    public void setCarLocationManager(CarLocationManager carLocationManager) {
        this.carLocMgr = carLocationManager;
    }
    
    public List<String> getLocationDetails(String id) {
        
        
        return carLocMgr.getCarLocationByQuery("id="+id);
        
    }
}
```

I tried to modify the getCarLocationDisplay method as follows but wondering if I'm proceeding in right direction as I need to return object but the return type is String and if I go and change the `return result` to `return dispplayObj` what should be the return type of the method?

```
public String getCarLocationDisplay() {

        String result = "";
        if (carHandler != null) {
            result = carHandler.getAttribute(CarHandler.CAR_LOCATION);
            CarLocationDisplay displayObj = new CarLocationDisplay();
            displayObj.getLocationDetails(result);            
        }
        return result;
}
```

**My attempt:**

```
public CarLocationDisplay getCarLocationDisplay() {
              
            CarLocationDisplay displayObj = null;              
            String result = "";
            if (carHandler != null) {
                result = carHandler.getAttribute(CarHandler.CAR_LOCATION);
                displayObj = new CarLocationDisplay();
                displayObj.getLocationDetails(result);            
            }
        return displayObj;
}
```

Comment: It sounds as though you need a `Car` class, with fields like `id`, `location`, and perhaps others. You can create an instance of `Car` in `getCarLocationDisplay` and return it, so the return type is `Car`.

Comment: I have a `Car` class with all those fields. If I create an instance of `Car` in  `getCarLocationDisplay` then how am I going to use the `CarLocationDisplay` class in which the method `getLocationDetails` is responsible for returning things based on the `id`. FYI - I'm using hibernate here with XML mapping files and `Car` class contains the exact parameters that exists in the database.

Comment: Why do you want to return `Object` instead of actual value. In the JSP you won't able to write an object to the response. It's not clear where the object is located and its scope. Because you didn't put this object as an attribute it's not available to JSP expression.

Comment: @RomanC Because in the hyperlink, I want to send `id` to other page when user clicks on it and display `name`  as the hyperlink text. I've added my attempt by editing my post and in JSP I'm expecting it to access like `${viewOrder.carLocationDisplay.id} or ${viewOrder.carLocationDisplay.name}`

Comment: But you can't use this object because you have not gettets for `id` and `name`.

Comment: I have a separate `Car` class with getters and setters for `id` , `name` and other fields (not shown above) which is basically used with hibernate mapping that I've done with XML. Using legacy hibernate and hence XML mappings.

Comment: If you have a separate `Car` class then you should retrieve it from the database, then you can initialize a view object with it's properties.